# create reusable iOS controls

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, code-reuse

I am new to iOS,

I am trying to searching the best approach for creating reusable controls in iOS4+. For example if I created a View that could be used in multiple other views what is the best approach ?

I have created the View Called: HomeViewController.h HomeViewController.m HomeViewController.xib

in my **HomeViewController** file i have created 5 buttons and 5 labels programatically, there is nothing in **.xib** file

Now what i want to do is, i want to reuse all the components which i have created in **HomeViewController** and i want to use this control in my **nextViewController**

I do not want to write code again in my new View i will use my old code in a new View,
In short i do not want to create same variable again in my new View.

**Is there any way to achieve this ?**

**Any help will be appriciated.**

Comment: " i have created 5 buttons and 5 labels programatically, there is nothing in .xib file" - you rock!

Comment: Means i created buttons and labels progrmatically in my `.m` file not by draging from `.xib` file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind:

- create a new object that has only the code that you want to re-use
  and have your two view controllers each use an instance of that object
  to perform the common functions, or
- create an abstract superclass that both of your view controllers
  inherit from and put the common code in it.

Comment: I would definately accept this answer, as well as pointing out the the second option is the definitive best way in my opinion. +1